# How Can I get value from a button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to get the value from a Button in Javascript. This is my code:

```js
    for(i=0; i<cars.length;i++){
    
    var p = `<button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()" value="${cars[i]}">${cars[i]}</button>`
        
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myBtn").value;
        console.log(x)
    }
```

But, I have this error:

```
(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)
```

How can I fix that? Thank you very much.

Comment: try myFunction()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick=myFunction` needs to be `onclick=myFunction()` so that the function gets invoked when the buttons are clicked. Without the `()`, JavaScript thinks that `myFunction` is a variable name, which it isn't, so it's `undefined`, hence your error.

Beyond that, your going to have problems making many buttons with the same `id`'s. ID`s must be unique.

And, your `myFunction` function shouldn't be in the loop.

Lastly, because each button should have a unique ID, an easier way to handle referencing the right one in your function is to pass a reference to the button into the function.

```js
function myFunction(btn) {
  console.log(btn.value)
}

var cars = ["Jeep", "Audi", "BMW", "Ford", "Chrysler", "Mercedes"];
for(var i=0; i<cars.length;i++){
    var p = `<button onclick="myFunction(this)" value="${cars[i]}">${cars[i]}</button>`
    document.body.innerHTML += p;
}
```

Now, all of that is what you'd need to do to get the code as you were trying to write it working, but you shouldn't be using inline HTML event handling attributes or building strings of HTML in the first place. Those are ancient techniques that have their issues. The modern, standards-based way to do it would be to separate your HTML from your JavaScript and create DOM elements and configure them via properties:

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log(this.value);
}

var cars = ["Jeep", "Audi", "BMW", "Ford", "Chrysler", "Mercedes"];

// Use the Array.forEach() method for easier array looping
cars.forEach(function(car){
    // Create elements instead of strings
    var b = document.createElement("button");
    
    // Then just configure their properties
    b.value = car;
    b.textContent = car;
    
    // And set up event handlers in JavaScript, not HTML
    b.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
    
    // Update the document to include the new element
    document.body.appendChild(b);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute the function on click

```
var p = `<button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()" value="${cars[i]}">${cars[i]}</button>`
```